# VB.NET LINQ - Matching Hierarchical Data to Flat Data

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have 2 representations of similar data from 2 different systems and I need to match each entity in one system with the entities in the other.

System A is Hierarchical, represented as a `Dictionary(Of String, List(Of CategoryA))` looking something like:

```
- "Organization 1" 
    - { Name = "Cat1", Id = 1}
    - { Name = "Cat2", Id = 2}
    - { Name = "Cat3", Id = 3}

- "Organization 2" 
    - { Name = "Cat1", Id = 4}
    - { Name = "Cat3", Id = 5}
    - { Name = "Cat4", Id = 6}

- "Organization 3" 
    - { Name = "Cat1", Id = 7}
    - { Name = "Cat2", Id = 8}
    - { Name = "Cat3", Id = 9}
    - { Name = "Cat4", Id = 10}
```

System B is Flattened, represented as a `List(Of CategoryB)` looking something like:

```
- { Org = "Organization 1", Name = "Cat1", Id = 100 }
- { Org = "Organization 1", Name = "Cat2", Id = 101 }
- { Org = "Organization 1", Name = "Cat3", Id = 102 }

- { Org = "Organization 2", Name = "Cat1", Id = 103 }
- { Org = "Organization 2", Name = "Cat2", Id = 104 }
- { Org = "Organization 2", Name = "Cat4", Id = 105 }

- { Org = "Organization 4", Name = "Cat1", Id = 106 }
- { Org = "Organization 4", Name = "Cat2", Id = 107 }
- { Org = "Organization 4", Name = "Cat3", Id = 108 }
- { Org = "Organization 4", Name = "Cat4", Id = 109 }
```

And basically what I need to do is to outer join the hierarchical data to the flattened data on Organization name (`Dictionary.Key` to `CategoryB.Org`) and Category Name (`CategoryA.Name` to `CategoryB.Name`), leaving me with a `Dictionary(Of String, IEnumerable(Of Tuple(Of CategoryA, CategoryB)))` or something that looks something like:

```
- "Organization 1" 
    - { Name = "Cat1", Id = 1}, { Org = "Organization 1", Name = "Cat1", Id = 100 }
    - { Name = "Cat2", Id = 2}, { Org = "Organization 1", Name = "Cat2", Id = 101 }
    - { Name = "Cat3", Id = 3}, { Org = "Organization 1", Name = "Cat3", Id = 102 }

- "Organization 2" 
    - { Name = "Cat1", Id = 4}, { Org = "Organization 2", Name = "Cat1", Id = 103 }
    - { Name = "Cat3", Id = 5}, null
    - { Name = "Cat4", Id = 6}, { Org = "Organization 2", Name = "Cat4", Id = 105 }

- "Organization 3" 
    - { Name = "Cat1", Id = 7}, null
    - { Name = "Cat2", Id = 8}, null
    - { Name = "Cat3", Id = 9}, null
    - { Name = "Cat4", Id = 10}, null
```

I don't have access to the `CategoryA` object to be able to apply an Organization property to it, or I would do it and make this easier on myself.  I just can't figure out how to join on the Dictionary key and a property of one of the items in its value, and end up with anything useful.  The most successful implementation I've created involves a `For Each` loop first, and a LINQ query inside:

```
Given:
    catA = Dictionary(Of String, List(Of CategoryA))
    catB = List(Of CategoryB)

Dim result As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of Tuple(Of CategoryA, CategoryB)))

For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, List(Of CategoryA)) In catA
    Dim orgName As String = kvp.Key

    If Not result.ContainsKey(orgName) Then
        result.Add(orgName, New List(Of Tuple(Of CategoryA, CategoryB)))
    End If

    Dim orgCategories As IEnumerable(Of CategoryB) =
        From cat In catB Where cat.Org = orgName

    Dim tmpResult As IEnumerable(Of Tuple(Of CategoryA, CategoryB)) =
        From cat_a In kvp.Value
        Group Join cat_b In orgCategories
            On cat_a.Name Equals cat_b.Name
        Into matchedCats = Group
        From cat In matchedCats.DefaultIfEmpty
        Select matches = Tuple.Create(cat_a, cat)

    result(orgName).AddRange(tmpResult)
Next
```

It works alright, but I'd like it to be in the same statement.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this kinda works but id stick with your for loop!

```
Public Class CategoryA
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Id As Integer
End Class

Public Class CategoryB
    Public Property Org As String
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Id As Integer
End Class

Private SystemA As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of CategoryA))
Private SystemB As New List(Of CategoryB)

Sub Main()
    SystemA.Add("Org1", New List(Of CategoryA) From {New CategoryA() With {.Id = 1, .Name = "Cat1"},
                                                     New CategoryA() With {.Id = 2, .Name = "Cat2"},
                                                     New CategoryA() With {.Id = 3, .Name = "Cat3"}})
    SystemA.Add("Org2", New List(Of CategoryA) From {New CategoryA() With {.Id = 4, .Name = "Cat1"},
                                                     New CategoryA() With {.Id = 5, .Name = "Cat2"},
                                                     New CategoryA() With {.Id = 6, .Name = "Cat3"}})
    SystemA.Add("Org3", New List(Of CategoryA) From {New CategoryA() With {.Id = 7, .Name = "Cat1"},
                                                     New CategoryA() With {.Id = 8, .Name = "Cat2"},
                                                     New CategoryA() With {.Id = 9, .Name = "Cat3"},
                                                     New CategoryA() With {.Id = 10, .Name = "Cat4"}})

    SystemB.Add(New CategoryB() With {.Org = "Org1", .Name = "Cat1", .Id = 100})
    SystemB.Add(New CategoryB() With {.Org = "Org1", .Name = "Cat2", .Id = 101})
    SystemB.Add(New CategoryB() With {.Org = "Org1", .Name = "Cat3", .Id = 102})
    SystemB.Add(New CategoryB() With {.Org = "Org2", .Name = "Cat1", .Id = 103})
    SystemB.Add(New CategoryB() With {.Org = "Org2", .Name = "Cat2", .Id = 104})
    SystemB.Add(New CategoryB() With {.Org = "Org2", .Name = "Cat4", .Id = 105})
    SystemB.Add(New CategoryB() With {.Org = "Org4", .Name = "Cat1", .Id = 106})
    SystemB.Add(New CategoryB() With {.Org = "Org4", .Name = "Cat2", .Id = 107})
    SystemB.Add(New CategoryB() With {.Org = "Org4", .Name = "Cat3", .Id = 108})
    SystemB.Add(New CategoryB() With {.Org = "Org4", .Name = "Cat4", .Id = 109})


    Dim AllOrgs = SystemA.Keys.Union(SystemB.Select(Function(b) b.Org).Distinct)

    Dim BothCats2 = From org In AllOrgs
                    Let CatAList = If(Not SystemA.ContainsKey(org), New List(Of CategoryA), From cat In SystemA(org))
                    Let CatBList = (From cat In SystemB Where cat.Org = org).ToList
                    Let AllCatNames = (From cat In CatAList Select cat.Name Distinct).Union(From cat In CatBList Select cat.Name Distinct)
                    Let BothCats = (From cat In AllCatNames
                                    From A In CatAList.Where(Function(CatA) CatA.Name = cat).DefaultIfEmpty
                                    From B In CatBList.Where(Function(CatB) CatB.Name = cat).DefaultIfEmpty)
                    Select org, BothCats

End Sub
```